# Confusion about usage of $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Tags: php, ssl, server

When `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` exists and has value other than **'off'** does that mean server supports secured connections or actual request is made using `https://`.

I'm looking for a way to detect possibility of using secured connection on a server even when request is made by using HTTP protocol.

Unfortunatelly, at the moment I don't have access to any server that supports SSL so I can't test it myself.

Is `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` present even when request is made like 'http://something' and SSL is enabled and configured for that server?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php says `'HTTPS'
Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.`. I think that's fairly clear? It tells you the current request is being made using HTTPS. It says nothing about whether it's possible to do so in general, or not. If you don't have access to the server's settings, then the only way to know if a server allows HTTPS requests is to try and make one. And bear in mind, that doesn't necessarily mean it supports HTTPS for all URLs, it's perfectly possible for it to be enabled only for certain ones.

Comment: @ADyson I've seen that but also ISAPI with IIS sets value of HTTPS to 'off' which is not non-empty value, right?

Comment: I haven't seen that personally. But it still tells you whether the request itself is being made via HTTPS or not. It doesn't tell you anything else about the server. The exact value being returned doesn't change the functionality which was used to generate it.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I understand that... just pointing out that what is written in documentation can't be considered to be a cross-server truth. Anyway, it still doesn't detect when SSL is enabled, which makes my search for an answer complete. Thanx for your time.

Comment: No problem. BTW did you actually go to that bit of the documentation? I've just gone back there, there is a note right underneath the bit I've already quoted which says _Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be **off** if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol._ :-)

Comment: @ADyson Actually didn't go that far, or didn't pay enough attention. Checked several online resources but was looking for a way to detect SSL and thought that HTTPS may be an answer, but clearly it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server) sais:

> Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.

It is only set, if called via https.

'off' is only used on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

php.net docs says about $_SERVER['HTTPS']

> 'HTTPS' Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the
>   HTTPS protocol.

Its means that you can check if the request was made over https or not.

To check if a server has installed a ssl cert you can use an online service like
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html